# Не отображается метка на Yandex Maps

Tags: javascript, php, yandex-maps-api

Не выводятся Placemark на карту Яндекса.

```
<script>
    ymaps.ready(init);

    function init () {
        var coordinate = <?=CUtil::PhpToJSObject($resultativ);?>;
        var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
                center: [55.76, 37.64],
                zoom: 9
            });
            for (var i = 0, l = coordinate.length; i < l; i++) {
            myPlacemark1 = new ymaps.Placemark([coordinate[i]], {
                iconContent: ' ',
                hintContent: 'г.Москва, ул.Ленина 12'
            }, {
                preset: 'twirl#redIcon'
            });
            alert (coordinate[i]);
            myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark1);
        }
    }
</script>
```

В то же время при выводе `alert (coordinate[i]);` - массив перебирает координаты, тобишь работает, но в формате: `55.763775,37.526462`, обычно указано формат в документациях Яндекса: `[55.763775,37.526462]`

Как исправить? Что можно придумать, чтобы вывело Placemark? Вторые сутки кручусь... Возможно добавить как-то к координатам []?

```
myPlacemark1 = new ymaps.Placemark([coordinate[i]] - пробовал такой формат


myPlacemark1 = new ymaps.Placemark(coordinate[i] - и такой..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Разбейте массив координат на чанки по 2 элемента.

2 - Используйте коллекцию координат указанную в документации Яндекс Карт по ссылке:
https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/geo_object_collection

3 - дока по хинтам и баллунам:
https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/balloon_and_hint

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init () {
    const coordinate = ["55.766546546,37.64546456", "55.743429,37.6643242"];
    const pointCoords = [];
    let myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
       center: [55.76, 37.64],
       zoom: 9
    });
    const collection = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection(null, {
        preset: 'twirl#redIcon'
    });

    for (let i = 0; i < coordinate.length; i++) {
       collection.add(new ymaps.Placemark(coordinate[i]
          .split(',').map(coord => +Number(coord).toFixed(2)),
          {
            iconContent: ' ',
            hintContent: "Хинт метки",
            balloonContent: "Содержимое <em>балуна</em> метки"
          }
        ));
    }

    myMap.geoObjects.add(collection)
}
```

```css
body, html {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }
 #map {
   width: 100%;
   height: 90%;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&amp;apikey=01d57a46-2d2e-40ee-9d47-f94e68ee1b0e"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: ``const collection = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection(null, {
        preset: 'twirl#redIcon'
    });``

Тут была запятая вместо ; в конце. Заменил, вывело один placemark, но он тягается по карте за мышкой, в общем пока что-то не так :(

Comment: Выше описал, скорее всего где-то есть опять трабл :(

Comment: вижу, смотрю  минчаррестрикт

Comment: @АндрейКотов проверяйте

Comment: @АндрейКотов с кодом все должно быть ок. что приходит в массив coordinate ?

Comment: ``array(1) { [0]=> string(19) "55.527662,37.586104" }``

Координаты приходят с элементов в таком формате.

Comment: @АндрейКотов сорри, не могу понять синтаксис... ребус какой-то. coordinate - это массив, где каждый элемент это строка типа "55.527662,37.586104" ? Чтобы код работал нужно получать coordinate в виде массива, где каждый элемент это значение координаты в числовом формате [*широта объекта 1*, *долгота объекта 1*, *широта объекта 2*, *долгота объекта 2*]

Comment: Это битрикс, но код в целом в нём запустился и работает (тот который без массива coordinate). Да. Получается, что вывожу с элемента каждого строку с координатами в том, формате что и писал. После чего в массив кидаю в цикле, чтобы можно было вывести все координаты за пределами того цикла.
Примерно так: ``$resultativ[] = $resULT2['ADRESS_KOORD']['VALUE'];``

Comment: @АндрейКотов сек, добавлю обработчик, который будет разбивать каждую строку на нужный нам формат

Comment: @АндрейКотов принимайте. все должно быть ок, если я правильно понял формат приходящих данных

Comment: Спасибо! ЛУЧШИЙ.

Comment: Ранее так же было окно всплывающее на метках:
``myPlacemark1 = new ymaps.Placemark([55.8, 37.6], {
                iconContent: ' ',
                balloonContent: '<span class="zl-info__map-item zl-info__map-item_loc">г.Москва, ул.Ленина 12</span>\n' +
                    '                                <a href="tel:8 (495) 129-27-81" class="zl-info__map-item zl-info__map-item_phone">8\n' +
                    '                                    (495) 129-27-81</a>\n' +``

Comment: Как теперь его возможно обратно запихать? В документацию полез, так и не нашлось похожего :/

Comment: ``iconContent: ' ',
balloonContent: 
hintContent:``

То что было в самом плейсмарке

Comment: @АндрейКотов щас гляну

Comment: @АндрейКотов обновил

Comment: @АндрейКотов в примере баллун открывается снизу фрейма из-за ограничений в размере окна, в приложении будет открываться нормально